# How to take the mean along an axis of a list in python without numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

In short, I'd like to recreate numPy's `mean(axis)` function using no dependencies for a matrix of unknown shape. numPy source code is near indecipherable and it's tough finding any statistics-based resources with all of the numPy resources drowning them out. I know the method will have to be recursive, as the length of the dimensions tuple could be anything, but I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Please note libraries like numpy exist for a reason, notably performance (with C bindings and GPU acceleration). Writing vanilla python to go over large n-dimensional matrices will be slow.

Comment: @Max yes, I'm aware. The project I'm working on cannot have any dependencies whatsoever

Comment: About `I don't even know where to start`: start writing your code for a large 3D array, this will give you the `mean` logic + an idea about performance. Then write for 4D and see how you can adapt code to generalize to n-dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a crazy question!!!

Could you explain what type of project is this that you cannot use numpy but you can use python??

```
def arrayItems(array, i0 = []):
    try:
        for i, ai in enumerate(array):
            yield from arrayItems(ai, i0 + [i])
    except TypeError as _:
        yield i0, array
        
def arrayShape(array):
    shape = [];
    while True:
        try:
            axLen = 0;
            for ai in array:
                axLen += 1;
            array = ai;
            shape.append(axLen)
        except TypeError:
            return shape;
        
def arrayZeros(shape):
    if len(shape) == 0:
        return 0;
    else:
        a0 = shape[0]
        shape = shape[1:]
        return [arrayZeros(shape) for _ in range(a0)]

# multiply accumulate, very good instruction
def arrayAcc(array, index, a=1, b=0):
    for i in index[:-1]:
        array = array[i]
    array[index[-1]] = a * array[index[-1]] + b;

def arrayMean(array, axis=0):
    inShape = arrayShape(array)
    axis = axis % len(inShape)
    out = arrayZeros(inShape[:axis] + inShape[axis+1:])
    for item in arrayItems(array):
        index, val = item
        arrayAcc(out, index[:axis] + index[axis+1:], 1.0, val / inShape[axis])
    return out;
```

A simple test

```
import numpy as np
testData = np.random.randn(2,3,4,5);

for axis in range(testData.ndim):
    assert(np.allclose(arrayMean(testData, axis), np.mean(testData, axis)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly! I'm not really allowed to talk about it, but the general gist is that I need a matrix-operation-heavy program to run on lightweight devices, which means no dependencies. Your multiply accumulate and mean methods will really help out!